# Keep agent active in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want a service to be active always in the background. Is this possible in the new SDK 7.1

I read through the Background File Transfers, Agents, and Alarms. I think these are only active for a period of time.

Comment: Why someone in this world rate it a negative

Comment: I agree with Praneeth: it's a perfectly reasonable question and it's a programming question. This is borne out by the fact that people were able to answer it directly. That said, I wish people in Praneeth's position would THINK. There's a REASON MS can't allow 3rd party processes to run indefinitely. It's a phone. Limited RAM, bandwidth and CPU.

Comment: Peter I really appreciate your response here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't

[Background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) can only run for 15 seconds every ~30 minutes. Attempting to run for longer will result in the agent being terminated and not rescheduled. [Riho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162266/keep-agent-active-in-windows-phone/8162804#8162804) is referring to something different: if the user does not run the owner application for 14 days your agent won't be rescheduled (even if it's successful); the application must be run and reschedule the agent.

Your only real choice is to move the functionality to the server and use [push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402558%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to update the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Agent gets deactivated after 14 days. Within that time you must make user to open your foreground application - then you can restart the agent and 14 days counter again.

Comment: How can keep the agent active for 14 days??

Comment: it stays active automatically

Comment: documentation doesn't say anything about it. can you please point me to the right link